# (Android) How do I update the displayed contents of a TableLayout in response to an event?

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

I am trying to learn Android app programming by building an app to keep score in Hearts. The data for the game itself is arranged in the following hierarchy:

- `Game` represents the whole game

  - `Vector` of `Round` objects representing each hand in the game.

    - `Vector` of `BoxScore` objects representing each box score in a hand.

This data is presented in a `ScoreTableActivity` by a `TableLayout`, where each `TableRow` contains a marker cell, a cell for each `BoxScore` object, and a cell which indicates whether the hand's total score is correct.  The final row of the table shows each player's total score, by adding up the box scores in each column.

I have a method `drawScoreTable()` which is called during the activity's `onCreate()` method, and it is working as expected.  While creating the cells for box scores, I have the following to catch clicks on those cells:

```java
TextView txtScore = ScoreTableCellFactory.getBoxScoreCell( this, oScore ) ;
txtScore.setOnClickListener(this) ;             
rowRound.addView( txtScore ) ; // rowRound is a TableRow.
```

The `ScoreTableActivity` itself implements `OnClickListener` in order to support this; only the box scores are clickable.  The activity's `onClick()` method is as follows:

```java
public void onClick( View oClicked )
{
    // A reference to the score object is built into the view's tag.
    BoxScore oScore = (BoxScore)oClicked.getTag() ;

    // Create the dialog where the user modifies the box score.
    BoxScoreEditorDialogFragment fragBoxScoreDialog = new BoxScoreEditorDialogFragment() ;
    fragBoxScoreDialog.setBoxScore(oScore) ;
    fragBoxScoreDialog.setRules(m_oGame.getRules()) ;
    fragBoxScoreDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragBoxScore") ;

    // We passed the BoxScore object across to the editor dialog by
    // reference (It's Java, after all), so we should be able to
    // update the text of the box score cell by simply re-examining
    // the data in that BoxScore object.
    ((TextView)oClicked).setText(Integer.toString(oScore.getScore())) ;

    // And it's at this point that something else is clearly needed.
}
```

Other answers on this site have suggested that the `setText()` method is enough to convince the renderer to refresh the cell, but it is not. With the code as it is above, the cell is not refreshed until the *next* time that the cell is clicked.

I have tried using the `invalidate()` method on the cell itself, its parent row, and the entire `TableLayout`, but none of these had any effect. I even tried using the `removeAllViews()` method and then calling `drawScoreTable()` again; even *that* didn't update the screen until after the next click event was caught.

If I tilt the tablet to a new orientation (from portrait to landscape or vice versa) then the entire activity is recreated and the new table shows all the correct data.  I would rather not resort to completely destroying and rebuilding the whole table but I thought that's what I was doing with `removeAllViews()` and even *that* didn't work.

### EDIT: Forceful solution found.

Part of the problem stems from the fact that the data update comes from the dialog.  This is a separate arena from the basic activity, so the dialog needs to trigger something when it exits.

My code is a bit more specialized but I've created a general example below to give you a context-free idea of what's going on.  It's actually based on the [official Android reference for "Dialogs"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents), which I unfortunately read only after posting this question.

#### Step 1: Create a custom listener class for the dialog.

```java
/**
 * Callers of this dialog must implement this interface to catch the events
 * that are returned from it.
 */
public interface Listener
{
    public void onDialogCommit( MyDialogClass fragDialog ) ;
}
```

#### Step 2: Implement the listener in your base activity.

At the head of your main activity class:

```java
public class MyBaseActivity
 extends Activity
 implements OnClickListener, MyDialogClass.Listener
```

I've kept the `OnClickListener` here because my code also catches the clicks that trigger the dialog's creation.  If you handle this with inline inner classes, then you don't need the `OnClickListener` in your `implements` clause.

#### Step 3: Implement the listener's interface in your base activity.

This is the part that's left out of the official Android example -- What do you do put into this listener method?  Well, the answer is surprisingly awful.

```java
public void onDialogCommit( MyDialogClass oDialog )
{
    TableLayout oLayout = (TableLayout)(findViewById(R.id.tbl_MyTableLayout)) ;
    // This is where things still seem more ugly than they should.
    oLayout.removeAllViews() ;
    this.recreateEverything() ; // assumes you've written a method for this
}
```

#### Surprises

Even after creating this new interface-and-listener model, using the `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` methods still wasn't enough.  I had to `removeAllViews()` and recall the method that redraws the whole activity.  I still believe that, surely, there's a more efficient way of doing this, but I haven't yet found it.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for this. Stuck at the same issue. The tablelayout points to the right index but shows contents of previous text and not current text.

Comment: I partially solved my issue by calling arraylist.clear onBackPressed() so each time an element entered my table, it showed latest results.